# How can I extract array elements from cv2.findcontours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to use cv2.findcontours and python3 to get the endpoints of a line.
My image file is 1000X600 and contains only one line at about a 15 degree angle.
This is the array I get from my code.
total number of contouers found :  2
[array([[[865, 314]],

```
   [[864, 315]],

   [[863, 315]],

   ...,

   [[868, 314]],

   [[867, 314]],

   [[866, 314]]], dtype=int32)]
```

The endpoints of my line are aprox are:
X0,Y0 = 71, 317 and X1,Y1 = 967,310

The image I used is a test to generate a single set of cordinates from cv2.findcountours.

I want to use the endpoints to calculate slope so that I can deskew old tabulated documents prior to OCR.

Below is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#
#
# load raw image
#

imagefile = "1-line.png"
#
# load raw image
#
image = cv2.imread(imagefile)
# get the image size
#
h, w, c = image.shape
print('width:  ', w)
print('height: ', h)
print('channel:', c)


result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
#
# Detect horizontal lines
#
# Default settinga are 40, 1
#
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#
# Original parameters, don't remove
#
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
#
# Added temporay code
#
print ("total number of contouers found : ", str(len(cnts)))
#print ("Contours 0 is : ", cnts[0])
#print ("Contours 1 is : ", cnts[1])
#print ("Contours 1 is : ", cnts[2])

# end of added code


cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,122), 5)
    print ([c])

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

What I don't understand is the array structure of the contours returned.

As a newbie to cv2 and python I need all the help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try drawing the contours to visualize them?

Comment: [mre] please, including input data (data, not screenshots). why is this tagged `ocr`?

Comment: if you're following a tutorial, it's a **bad tutorial** and you should discard it. if not, please review OpenCV docs for this function so you will see what it returns in the Python case. -- `findContours` returns **multiple things**. say this: `(contours, hierarchy) = cv.findContours(...)` -- `contours` is a list of individual contours. each contour is a list of points. it's always closed. if you have a "line" in your picture, the contour will have the shape of a narrow rectangle, more or less.

Comment: I did draw a contour and it appeared around my line, but none of the values in the array correspond to the perimeter of the line as you can see from the orginal question.  There should be some values around the X0,Y0 value for my line.  There is something I am missing here.

Comment: I can't see your image, I can't run your code, and I can't read in your mind - so I have no idea what is your problem. You  have describe all details in question (not in comments). Better create minimal working code and add your image so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: My code was taggrd OCR because the end use for this program will be to act as image conditioning for OCR as I stated in my first post.
Sorry about not providing a image file for this question but I don't know how to upload a local file to Stackoverflow..
The image file is just a .png file 1000X500 with a white background.  THe single line is X0,Y0 = 71, 317 and X1,Y1 = 967,310 and is red.
The code I provided is the code I am using to get ther ruslts that showed originaly.
The code executes in a terminal window on Ubuntu 22.04.


Not sure, again amy help is apreciated.

Comment: ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post we require a [mre] because anything less is just a waste of time in the majority of cases. if you have trouble providing a picture, instead provide the code to generate it. sounds like you merely have a blank picture with a single straight line drawn on it. that's a single `cv.line` call

Comment: To simplify my problem, what I need is a link to where the actual array structure for the output of cv2.findcontouurs.  This will help me address what is actually being returned by the call.

Comment: what? did you just ask for documentation? well, https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html and I believe I already told you that it returns multiple things, and what the `contours` list contains. did you miss that? I'm not sure what you could still be possibly asking, given the information that is available to you. I find your question vague: "actual array structure for the output"